# Laravel postgres db return string instead int or float values

Tags: json, laravel, postgresql

We are working on the migration of a very large project with laravel and a postgres database, unfortunately for many queries we have to use them raw because they draw from currently existing postgres functions.

The problem is that the values defined at the db level on postgres as "int" and "float" are provided as strings instead of in the correct format.

I have already tried with the cast but since it is a raw query it does not go through it.
A solution found would be that, at the level of laravel, to apply
-> setEncodingOptions (JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) but in fact this way we have no control over what comes out as he - all numbers put them as non strings, the best thing for us would obviously be to have the correlation defined on db.

Answer (score 0):

temporarily fixed by setting:

```
select json_agg (t) from (QUERY_RAW SQL) t
```

json_agg is a postgres function that return data.

Hope there is another (better) solution for this.